# Find limits of integral

Tags: integration

I got this question:

> $f(x)=x+\ln(x)$
>   Prove that $f(a)\le\frac{1}{(b-a)}\int_a^b{f(x)dx}\le f(b)$ when $0<a<b$

First of all, I've wrote the question like that:
$(b-a)f(a)\le\int_a^b{f(x)dx}\le(b-a)f(b)$

I've found that
$\int_a^b{f(x)dx} = \frac{b^2}{2}+b(\ln(b)+1)-\frac{a^2}{2}+a(\ln(a)+1)$

and I've tried to manipulate $a$ and $b$ to get the bounds in the question.

The problem is that I don't know if $a$ or $b$ are less then 1, so I can't change the $\ln$s. For example, to reach to the upper bound, I somehow must to remove the $\ln(a)$, and I don't know anything about it...

Any ida how to solve this question?

Comment: Hint: Show $f$ is increasing on $(0,\infty).$

Comment: I've already did... I don't know how it can help me

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem for integrals?

Comment: Yes... I think that I understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $F(X)=\int{f(x)dx}$.

We know that $F(x)$ is differentiable (and continues) for every $x>0$.
From mean value theorem we know that there is a $c\in(a,b)$ that
$f(c)=\frac{F(a)-F(b)}{b-a}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b{f(x)dx}$

Because $f$ is increasing for on $(0,∞)$ and $a<c<b$
$f(a)\le f(c)\le f(b)$
And we've got
$f(a)\le \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b{f(x)dx}\le f(b)$

(Thanks to @md2perpe)

Comment: Notice that you don't actually use the explicit expression for $F(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0 <a <b $.

For $x>0$,
$$f (x)=x+\ln (x)$$
$$f'(x)=1+\frac {1}{x}>0$$
$\implies f $ increasing at $[a,b ] $.
$$\implies \forall x\in [a,b]  \; f (a)\le f (x)\le f (b )$$
$$\implies$$
$ f (a)(b-a)\le \int_a^bf (x)dx\le f (b)(b-a) $